# how to return results that have a date of yesterday and before

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, llblgenpro

I am returning results using the LLBLGen adapter model. using break points because I cannot get them to populate the kendo grid yet, I can see that they are all coming back. However I need to only return results that have a date property of yesterday and prior. I am not familiar at all using the kendo grid nor the LLBL adapter. The majority of other examples out there are using entity framework. here is what i have so far. There is no error messages because I am stuck at how to setup the filter?

Controller

```
public ActionResult BundleStatus()
    {
        return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BundleStatusRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {

            var span = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
            DataAccessAdapter adapter = new DataAccessAdapter();
            EntityCollection allBundles = new EntityCollection(new CarrierBundleEntityFactory());
            adapter.FetchEntityCollection(allBundles, null);
           var results = allBundles;

         return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

}
```

View

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "BundleStatusGet";
  }

 <div>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ZoomAudits.DAL.EntityClasses.CarrierBundleEntity>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.BundleId).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CarrierId).Width(190);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Date);
        columns.Bound(c => c.IsSent).Width(110);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(5))
                .Selectable(selectable => selectable
                .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple)
                .Type(GridSelectionType.Cell))
            //.Events(events => events.Change("onChange").Sync("sync_handler")))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("BundleStatusRead", "BundleStatus"))
                //.Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Grid"))
    )
)
```

Update Controller

```
public ActionResult BundleStatusRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {

            var span = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
            DataAccessAdapter adapter = new DataAccessAdapter();
            EntityCollection allBundles = new EntityCollection(new CarrierBundleEntityFactory());
            RelationPredicateBucket filter = new RelationPredicateBucket(CarrierBundleFields.Date == span);
            adapter.FetchEntityCollection(allBundles, filter);
           var results = allBundles;

         return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request));
```

it is not returning any results? this is what i see when i open up the break point at var results   LLBL Enumeration yielded no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I haven't used LLBLGen in a while and that was prior to the adapter. However, I found [this](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/3.5/LLBLGen%20Pro%20RTF/Using%20the%20generated%20code/Adapter/gencode_usingcollectionclasses_adapter.htm) documentation on Using the `EntityCollection<T>` class, Adapter for LLBLGen. Hope it helps.

By the way, you can also use `[HttpGet]` and set the action result to allow get.

```
return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If you are trying to get yesterday and prior then use:

```
RelationPredicateBucket filter = new RelationPredicateBucket(CarrierBundleFields.Date <= span);
```

Comment: it did get me a step further. I think? check out my edit

Comment: if there is no data in the database with yesterdays date that would be the correct response. correct? how do i set it so it does yesterday and prior?

Comment: Update answer with a possible solution.

Comment: thank you very much! now i need to work on the populating the grid

Comment: Can you take a look at my issue with the circular reference?    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399548/convert-llblgen-model-class-to-view-model-objects